# Pylint giving a false positive E1101 'no-member' error for 'http.HTTPStatus'

Tags: python, http, http-status-codes, pylint, pylintrc

I am using Pylint for code linting (inside Visual Studio Code with Pylint 2.3.1, [astroid](https://pypi.org/project/astroid/) 2.2.5, and Python 3.6.2).

The behavior can be reproduced with the following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from http import HTTPStatus

print(HTTPStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.phrase)
```

Linting this snippet by calling

```
pylint snippet.py
```

gives the following error message:

> E1101: Instance of 'NOT_ACCEPTABLE' has no 'phrase' member (no-member)

However, I think `.phrase` is a member of the given instance since the code is working, prints the desired result and `.phrase` is referenced in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html#http.HTTPStatus). Which leads to the assumption that the error message is a false positive.

I then had a look at the Pylint configuration options in [its own documentation](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options) and in the [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_commandline-arguments-and-configuration-files) and generated a `.pylintrc` file by executing

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc
```

Inside this configuration file I was able to find the following line:

```
enable=c-extension-no-member
```

Commenting out this line and thus disabling the `c-extension-no-member` checks, the false positive `E1101` error message is suppressed.

However, I am still wondering whether this is just a workaround or a real false positive, since it disables all `c-extension-no-member` checks and seems to be unsuitable for a general approach. For sure, one can specify specific modules to ignore on performing the checks, but I just want to know the reason for this error message.